# P normal cone of a cone metric space, given $\epsilon > 0$, can we choose c interior point of P ($c \gg 0$) s.t $\|c\| < \epsilon/K$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-cone, dual-cone

I get this statment from paper "Cone metric spaces and fixed point theorems
of contractive mappings
Huang Long-Guang, Zhang Xian", i failed to understand why there is a guarantee that we can choose an interior point, given $\epsilon >0$ such that $\|c\|<\epsilon / K$, where $K$ is the normal constant.

Comment: This is unclear. $c$ is an interior point with respect to what subset of $E$? Entire space $E$? The interior of $E$ is $E$ itself (since it is open in itself). So are you asking: if $0$ is a limit point in $E$ then does there exist a nonzero element arbitrarly close (with respect to the norm) to $0$? This is pretty much the definition of being a limit point.

Comment: yes, i forgot the subset ,. i'v just edited it..

Comment: This is false. The interior of a closed subset need not be nonempty. For example take $P=\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. Some additional assumptions are needed. Like perhaps $0\in\text{int}(P)$?

Comment: sorry, i think  my question is not for general normed space,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [page 1469](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82146514.pdf), it says that it is assumed that $P$ is a cone with non-empty interior. Therefore there is some $c_1$ in the interior $P$. But then $ac_1$ is also in the interior of $P$ for any $a > 0$. Hence setting $c=ac_1$ and choosing $a$ sufficiently small will satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Wow.. thank you, that is really helpful,. but how can i proof $K||c|| < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: @zainudinsaputra - Since you can choose $a$ to be any size, you can make $\|c\|$ as small as you want.

Comment: Oke thank you...